# SOAP UI Restful : An error occurred [Illegal character in path at index

Tags: java, rest, web-services, testing, soapui

I am currently developing a Web Service RESTFUL. 
To test the Web Service, I'm using SOAP UI.

While performing testing, I got the error Illegal character in path.
May I know what is the cause of the error? How to fix the issue?
Below is the detail of the problem.

Error Log:

```
Wed Nov 28 17:05:26 SGT 2018:ERROR:java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 62: http://127.0.0.1:8080/AdaptiveAuthWSApps/rest/AdaptiveService/{uuid}/{browserinfo}/{ipint}/{lat}/{longitude}/{sessionid}/{spid}/{tr}/{jsnum}/{fingerprint}/{methodset}
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 62: http://127.0.0.1:8080/AdaptiveAuthWSApps/rest/AdaptiveService/{uuid}/{browserinfo}/{ipint}/{lat}/{longitude}/{sessionid}/{spid}/{tr}/{jsnum}/{fingerprint}/{methodset}
```

SOAP UI Log:

```
Wed Nov 28 17:05:26 SGT 2018:ERROR:An error occurred [Illegal character in path at index 62: http://127.0.0.1:8080/AdaptiveAuthWSApps/rest/AdaptiveService/{uuid}/{browserinfo}/{ipint}/{lat}/{longitude}/{sessionid}/{spid}/{tr}/{jsnum}/{fingerprint}/{methodset}], see error log for details
Wed Nov 28 17:05:26 SGT 2018:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Wed Nov 28 17:05:26 SGT 2018:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /?uuid=iz23456&browserinfo=Mozilla%2F8.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.1%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F49.0.2623.112%20Safari%2F537.36&ipint=16885247&lat=1&longitude=0&sessionid=12w3e4&spid=https%3A%2F%2Fuap%2Fowa&tr=10&jsnum=2&fingerprint=yh8u87&methodset=1%2C1 HTTP/1.1
Wed Nov 28 17:05:26 SGT 2018:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 
Wed Nov 28 17:05:26 SGT 2018:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
```

Below is the WADL  that I used when creating the Test Suite in SOAP UI.

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/AdaptiveAuthWSApps/rest/application.wadl

SOAP UI parameter initialize:

[image]

Comment: `{` and `}` are the illegal characters. You need to URL encode them. You can use the URLEncoder class. You can see in the error message: _"Illegal character in path at index 62"_ - **index 62**. That's the `{`. Gotta thoroughly read the error messages man.

Comment: Are those just placeholders, and you are supposed to replace those `{xxx}` with real values?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the value of your uuid parameter.

A uuid should consist solely of hexadecimal characters. That is 0-9 and a-f (and also the "-" of course)

You've written iz123456, and neither "i" or "z" are valid.

If the uuid also should be an actual uuid, then it should look something like this: 13a1a079-4a39-4625-91a4-ddbf09c2c324

Try copy/pasting this uuid into your uuid parameter, and run it again.

Comment: hi,i already tried as per your suggestion but same thing happen.

Comment: I just tried to create a HTTP request in SoapUI / ReadyAPI. I created a URI like http://localhost:8080?param1=x&param2=y , and after I pressed Extract Params, the URI got cut down to just http://localhost:8080 and the parameters were moved down. So I think you need to change your endpoint. Remove everything after "AdaptiveService/"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting your parameter styles mixed up. If you define a style of `QUERY`, the key/value pairs are added after the question mark in the URL, not added to the resource path. Using `{uuid}/{browserinfo}/...` is a `TEMPLATE` style.

So, remove `{uuid}/{browserinfo}/...` from your resource path and just leave the key/value pairs after the question mark.